# Java: If variable is empty (from user input); break; else continue the main method

Tags: java, loops, break

sorry if this is a silly question but I am looking for a way to break and start another iteration of the loop if the user's input is null.
Here's my code:

```
while(true) {
    // Get the users input
    Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter text:");
    String studentInfo = Input.nextLine();

    if (studentInfo == null) {
        System.out.println("Please enter valid infomation.");
        break;
    }
    continue;
}
```

After the break, I want it to go back to the while(true) and start again from there, by asking the user for an input again.

Thanks guys,

JT

Comment: Note that `nextLine()` can never return `null`.

Comment: why do you need `break` than?

Comment: Aw okay, I didn't know that, I'm just trying to stop my code from crashing when the user just hits enter with no actual input, thanks guys though!

Comment: It is the intrinsic nature of (infinite) loops to start another iteration when the previous has finished. So no need for a break there.

Comment: I know but what I'm trying to achieve was to not  come up an error message when an empty input was used, instead just print a statement and carry on with the iteration. I have been answered now though so thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check for:

```
if (studentInfo.isEmpty()) {
    continue;
}
```

Remove the `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);` declaration from inside the `while` loop.